# gzgets reaches end of file early

Tags: php, zlib

I have a gzipped text file that I'm trying to read within PHP (using gzopen/gzgets). The file is somewhat large, around 158,000 lines. The script works fine except when it gets to line 157,237 of the file, it reads in part of the line then acts as if it's reached EOF. I'm able to unzip the file and confirm the rest of the file does exist. I wrote a simple script to test:

```
<?php
    $handle = gzopen('/path/to/file.gz','r');
    while(true) {
        echo gzgets($handle,4096);
    }
?>
```

It reads in everything perfectly then suddenly gets to this line and prints:

```
GUAN XIN 508|R34745|CH|CGO|100|
```

and nothing else. It just sits there [the not-infinite-loop version exits the while(!gzeof($handle))]

If I gunzip the file and go to that line, I see:

```
GUAN XIN 508|R34745|CH|CGO|100| | | | |BEGS| | | | |133|19| | | | | | | | | | | | |413669000|1|
```

So the data is there. Is there some sort of size limitation on the zlib functions that I'm not aware of?

UPDATE: I ran it through a 'cat -vet' to look for special characters... nothing.

Comment: Out of memory? I dont know what you do with all those lines, but if you create populated objects your memory could fill up pretty quick and You’d get a stack overflow.

Comment: I'd agree with you but in that mini script I posted, the same thing happens, even though it shouldn't be storing anything anywhere. I also already tried upping the php memory limit directive with no change.

Comment: I would suggest edit every word in turn, regzip, rerun script and find out which word breaks it. does it also break if you create a smaller file for testing with just 150 lines with in the middle your "break" eof line?

Comment: And if you’ve found the culprit i’d suggest you contact the makers of the gzip library you’re using with a bug report.

Comment: Hm, it's a long shot, but hey: does `gzopen('file.gz','rb');` alter anything?

Comment: Changing the mode to rb didn't change anything. I removed a line from the file and it now reads the "GUAN XIN" line correctly but fails on the following line. Looks like it is some sort of file size limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated zlib to 1.2.7. We were running 1.2.3, and "large file" support was apparently added in 1.2.4.

Comment: Glad you found that.  I find it perplexing that operating systems that support > 2 GB files require you to effectively say "Simon says" before they will let you read past the 2 GB (or sometimes 4 GB).  If you're not using seek operations, they should just let you keep reading to the end of the file, like it's always been.  (The "Simon says" in this case is putting "#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64" in the source code, or a different define to make *64 versions of the functions available and using those.)